# Mono Profile vs XCode Instruments. Descripencies

Tags: uitableview, mono, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, xamarin

I am profiling my app on an iPhone.  I am creating a LOT of `UIWebView` and sticking them in a MonoTouch.Dialog Table (lets say 1000).  I have a button that clears out the table section and disposes the webviews and any reference to any of the WebViews.

I notice with Mono Profile, that the instances of `UIWebview` goes down to zero (as it should).   However, if I do the same test using Instruments (Allocations), it shows that the number of "live" Webviews never decreases and the memory never recovers.  I even tried a GC.Collect and it made no difference.

I also see that Mono profile says that total ram being used is aroun 1.5 meg, when in Instruments shows around 5meg.

The first item concerns me more since it appears that I am unable to recover that memory and destroy all those instances. Am I reading this wrong or is there some other issue?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number of UIWebView instances go down in the Mono profiler, but not in Instruments, it means native code is holding a reference to those instances, preventing them from getting released.

I suggest you enable the "Record reference count" option in the Allocations instrument, and then investigate the retainCount when the UIWebView instances only show up in Instruments - you need to pair each retain call with a release call (but there will be at least one you can't pair up, and that's the one you're looking for). At this point you need to figure out why that retain call doesn't have a corresponding release call.

Neither the Mono profile nor the Allocations instrument actually tell you the total amount of ram being used (and they measure different things which is why the number is different). The Mono profiler only measures managed objects, while the Allocations object measures most (but not all) native allocations in addition to the managed ones.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful and confirms my thoughts.  I am disposing everything possible and calling GC.Collect with no luck, so I will have to put together a simple sample and see if it shows the issue.  Perhaps a bug in the native code.

Comment: I have confirmed that there is an issue with disposing of the webviews when they are hosted inside a dialog view controller.  I have created a bug for tracking.  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9846

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a misunderstanding.

- MonoTouch.Dialog is based on `UITableView`. It can hide a lot of its complexity but the underlying behaviour will still be identical;
- `UITableView` uses `UITableViewCell` instances. However to minimize the memory requirements it reuse the cells whenever possible. So a table with 1000 cells, showing only a dozen on the screen, might only need to allocate (no much more than) a dozen cells (not a 1000).

Normal (or MT.D) code looks like this:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("cell") as MyCell;
    if (cell == null) {
        // create new cell
        cell = new MyCell ();
    } else {
        // prepare cell for reuse
    }
    // customize cell
    return cell;
}
```

What's likely happening is that:

- you create 1000 elements;
- when asked the element creates a **new** cell, about 14 times to fill the screen, then it reuse them (e.g. if you scroll);
- `section.Clear` clears the UI (not the `UITableView` cell cache);
- Instruments shows you what `UITableView` has allocated (e.g. the 14 cached/reusable cells);
- Those cells will be freed when you dispose the `UITableView`, which is allocated by the `DialogViewController`. Otherwise the (cached) cells are not under your control;